# How to filter based on another file

Tags: linux, text, file-io

Say I have a file in this format
file 1:

```
kk a 1
rf c 3
df g 7
er e 4
es b 3
```

and another file 2:

```
c
g
e
```

I want filter the second column based on file 2 and output a file like this:

```
rf c 3
df g 7
er e 4
```

how would be the linux command for this?

Comment: Good edit, Olaf =)  Makes more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}($2 in A)' file2 file1
```

Comment: awk rawks! and I'm still learning new things -- I'd never seen the NR==FNR{} construct for reading the first of a list of files. This elegantly solves precisely the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) for this, if both files are sorted or in the correct order. Although this gives a different output

```
join --nocheck-order -1 2 -2 1 file1.txt file2.txt
```

gives

```
c rf 3
g df 7
e er 4
```

With perl, you can read the keys file and then check each line for a match

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %keys;
open(my $f1, '<', 'file2.txt') or die("Cannot open file2.txt: $!");
while (<$f1>) {
    chomp;
    $keys{$_} = 1;
}

close($f1);

open(my $f2, '<', 'file1.txt') or die("Cannot open file1.txt: $!");
while (<$f2>) {
    my(undef, $col2, undef) = split(' ', $_);
    print if ($keys{$col2});
}

close($f2);
```

This will give the desired

```
rf c 3
df g 7
er e 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily fast or pretty, but does the trick:

```
cut -f 2 -d ' ' file1 | while read letter; do grep -n "$letter" file2 | cut -d ':' -f 1 | while read lineNo; do sed $((lineNo+1))'!d' file1; done; done;
```